# Return value VarBinds pysnmp

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp

I've made my first Python SNMP agent from a custom MIB .

It is supporting SNMP GET and SET requests, but it returns values ​​pre-determined by me.

How do I make my function's returned varbinds' be the values ​​that users have supplied via their SNMP SETs?

The code:

```
from pysnmp.entity import engine, config
from pysnmp import debug
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413 import cmdrsp, context, ntforg
from pysnmp.carrier.asynsock.dgram import udp
from pysnmp.proto.rfc1902 import OctetString
from pysnmp.smi import builder

import threading
import collections
import time

#can be useful
debug.setLogger(debug.Debug('all'))

MibObject = collections.namedtuple('MibObject', ['mibName',
                                   'objectType', 'valueFunc'])

class Mib(object):
    """Stores the data we want to serve. 
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self._lock = threading.RLock()
        self._system_channel = 0
    self._system_programmed = 0


    def getSystemModel(self):
        return "Teste 1 Ok"

    def getTransportStream(self):
        return "Teste 2 Ok"

    def getSystemProgrammedPower(self):
        with self._lock:
        return self._system_programmed 

    def setSystemProgrammedPower(self, value):
    with self._lock:
        self._system_programmed = value     

    def getSystemChannel(self):
        with self._lock:
            return self._system_channel

    def setSystemChannel(self, value):
        with self._lock:
            self._system_channel = value


def createVariable(SuperClass, getValue, *args):
    """This is going to create a instance variable that we can export. 
    getValue is a function to call to retreive the value of the scalar
    """
    class Var(SuperClass):
        def readGet(self, name, *args):
            return name, self.syntax.clone(getValue())
    return Var(*args)


class SNMPAgent(object):
    """Implements an Agent that serves the custom MIB and
    can send a trap.
    """

    def __init__(self, mibObjects):
        """
        mibObjects - a list of MibObject tuples that this agent
        will serve
        """

        #each SNMP-based application has an engine
        self._snmpEngine = engine.SnmpEngine()

        #open a UDP socket to listen for snmp requests
        config.addSocketTransport(
        self._snmpEngine,
        udp.domainName,
        udp.UdpTransport().openServerMode(('127.0.0.1', 161))
    )
        # SNMPv3/USM setup


    config.addV1System(self._snmpEngine, 'test-agent', 'public')
    # user: usr-sha-none, auth: SHA, priv NONE
    config.addV3User(
        self._snmpEngine, 'test-user',
        config.usmHMACMD5AuthProtocol, 'authkey1',
        config.usmDESPrivProtocol, 'privkey1'
        )


        # Allow full MIB access for each user at VACM
    config.addContext(self._snmpEngine, '')
    config.addRwUser(self._snmpEngine, 1, 'test-agent', 'noAuthNoPriv', (1,3,6)) # v1
    config.addRwUser(self._snmpEngine, 2, 'test-agent', 'noAuthNoPriv', (1,3,6)) # v2c
    config.addRwUser(self._snmpEngine, 3, 'test-user', 'authPriv', (1,3,6)) # v3 

        #each app has one or more contexts
        self._snmpContext = context.SnmpContext(self._snmpEngine)

        #the builder is used to load mibs. tell it to look in the
        #current directory for our new MIB. We'll also use it to
        #export our symbols later
        mibBuilder = self._snmpContext.getMibInstrum().getMibBuilder()
        mibSources = mibBuilder.getMibSources() + (builder.DirMibSource('.'),)
        mibBuilder.setMibSources(*mibSources)

        #our variables will subclass this since we only have scalar types
        #can't load this type directly, need to import it
        MibScalarInstance, = mibBuilder.importSymbols('SNMPv2-SMI',
                                                      'MibScalarInstance')
        #export our custom mib
        for mibObject in mibObjects:
            nextVar, = mibBuilder.importSymbols(mibObject.mibName,
                                                mibObject.objectType)
            instance = createVariable(MibScalarInstance,
                                      mibObject.valueFunc,
                                      nextVar.name, (0,),
                                      nextVar.syntax)
            #need to export as <var name>Instance
            instanceDict = {str(nextVar.name)+"Instance":instance}
            mibBuilder.exportSymbols(mibObject.mibName,
                                     **instanceDict)

        # tell pysnmp to respotd to get, set, getnext, and getbulk
        cmdrsp.GetCommandResponder(self._snmpEngine, self._snmpContext)
        cmdrsp.NextCommandResponder(self._snmpEngine, self._snmpContext)
        cmdrsp.BulkCommandResponder(self._snmpEngine, self._snmpContext)
    cmdrsp.SetCommandResponder(self._snmpEngine, self._snmpContext)

    def setTrapReceiver(self, host, community):
        """Send traps to the host using community string community
        """
        config.addV1System(self._snmpEngine, 'nms-area', community)
        config.addVacmUser(self._snmpEngine, 2, 'nms-area', 'noAuthNoPriv',
                           notifySubTree=(1,3,6,1,4,1))
        config.addTargetParams(self._snmpEngine,
                               'nms-creds', 'nms-area', 'noAuthNoPriv', 1)
        config.addTargetAddr(self._snmpEngine, 'my-nms', udp.domainName,
                             (host, 162), 'nms-creds',
                             tagList='all-my-managers')
        #set last parameter to 'notification' to have it send
        #informs rather than unacknowledged traps
        config.addNotificationTarget(
            self._snmpEngine, 'test-notification', 'my-filter',
            'all-my-managers', 'trap')


    def sendTrap(self):
        print "Sending trap"
        ntfOrg = ntforg.NotificationOriginator(self._snmpContext)
        errorIndication = ntfOrg.sendNotification(
            self._snmpEngine,
            'test-notification',
            ('LINEARISDBLQ-MIB', 'systemCurrentAlarmTrap'),
            ())


    def serve_forever(self):
        print "Starting agent"
        self._snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.jobStarted(1)
        try:
           self._snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.runDispatcher()
        except:
            self._snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.closeDispatcher()
            raise

class Worker(threading.Thread):
    """Just to demonstrate updating the MIB
    and sending traps
    """

    def __init__(self, agent, mib):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self._agent = agent
        self._mib = mib
        self.setDaemon(True)

    def run(self): 
        while True:
            time.sleep(3)
            self._mib.setSystemChannel(mib.getSystemChannel()+1)
            self._agent.sendTrap()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mib = Mib()
    objects = [MibObject('LINEARISDBLQ-MIB', 'systemModel', mib.getSystemModel),
               MibObject('LINEARISDBLQ-MIB', 'systemChannel', mib.getSystemChannel),
           MibObject('LINEARISDBLQ-MIB', 'transportStream', mib.getTransportStream),
               MibObject('LINEARISDBLQ-MIB', 'systemProgrammedPower', mib.getSystemProgrammedPower)]
    agent = SNMPAgent(objects)
    agent.setTrapReceiver('127.0.0.1', 'traps')
    Worker(agent, mib).start()
    try:
        agent.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Shutting down"
```

Comment: To answer this question requires going through a lot of code. This makes it hard to give good answers without spending disproportionate amounts of time on the question; most people will rather move on to another question. If you distil the question down to the smallest possible sample that reproduces the problem the quantity, quality and clarity of answers you get will improve as well. The edited question does not have to do the same thing as the whole of the code, it only needs to reproduce the one aspect that you need help with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you designed your own MIB structures which are not connected to pysnmp engine.

To make your MIB variables available to pysnmp-based Agent, you have to either [A)](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/current/v3arch/agent/cmdrsp/v2c-custom-scalar-mib-objects.html) inherit  your MIB objects from pysnmp's MibScalarInstance class or [B)](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/current/v3arch/agent/cmdrsp/v3-alternative-mib-controller.html) build your own MIB Controller supporting pysnmp-compatible interfaces.

For more information please refer to the above examples.